# Strapi V4 : how can I restrict user update (PUT /users/:id) to only the user itself, and admins?

Tags: authentication, strapi, endpoint

I've enabled the *update* permissions for the *Authentificated* role of *Users-permissions*.

I noticed that now, any *Authentificated* user can update any other user using the `PUT /users/:id` endpoint.
That's a weird default behaviour !

I guess I have to add a policy to restrict this by editing `src/extensions/users-permissions/strapi-server.js`.

```
  ("use strict");

  module.exports = (plugin) => {

    //get api routes for 'user-permissions'
    const apiRoutes = plugin.routes['content-api'].routes;

        //add policies for PUT /users/:id
        apiRoutes
          .filter(route => route.handler === 'user.update')
          .map(route => {
            route.config.policies = [...]
            return route;
          });

      return plugin;

  };
```

What policies should I use (or create) to restrict that endpoint ?
I want to allow the access only if the user is updating his own profile, or if he has the 'Admin' role.

Is that possible ?

Thanks !

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74728231/why-all-users-in-strapi-have-access-to-update-all-users-profile/74734475#74734475